# common regex patterns for two strings

Tags: .net, regex, unix, hdfs

I can use one common regex pattern to grab groups from the following two strings
*show me light not fear

show me light and grace*

```
Regex: show me ([\w]+) (not ([\w]+)|and ([\w]+))
```

But I cannot find a common regex for below:
*show me light

show me light and grace*

```
Regex: show me ([\w]+)| and ([\w]+)
```

it treats "and grace" in second string as separate match, Can you please help me identify the mistake

Comment: You need [`show\s+me\s+(\w+)*(?:\s+and\s+(\w+))?`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=show%5cs%2bme%5cs%2b%28%5cw%2b%29*%28%3f%3a%5cs%2band%5cs%2b%28%5cw%2b%29%29%3f&i=show+me+light%0d%0ashow+me+light+and+grace)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you had it in a separate capture group.

[Try something like this](https://regex101.com/r/wS80KW/8)

`show me (\w+) ?(not|and)? ?(\w+)?`

Comment: Thanks it worked!! How does wrapping around with '?' work, as in the one where you used ?(not|and)?

Comment: I wasn't wrapping it with those. ` ?` was to have an optional space, then `(not|and)?` for an optional not or and, ` ?` for another optional space, and `(\w+)?` for an optional word. I made all of those optional so it would also match "show me light"

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Learnt about optional space

Answer (score 0):

The alternation operator `|` [has the lowest precedence](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/regex_3.html#SEC16), so your second example matches either `show me ([\w]+)` or `and ([\w]+)`.

Here is a [regex matching both strings](https://regexr.com/3sh7r): `show me ([\w]+)( and ([\w]+))?`